# What are the choices presented by this evil statue?

Tags: the-binding-of-isaac

I just found a strange "evil" statue in Binding of Isaac.

[image]

What are the effects of these offers?

Comment: It's not a statue, it's the devil!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is not a statue, but Satan, and you have found what's referred to as a "devil room". These two particular items are *Sister Maggy* (on the left), a familiar that follows you and shoots blood tears in the same direction that you do, and *The Mark*, which increases your damage by 2 points.

Be aware that the cost depicted in hearts will be deducted from your own heart containers, possibly killing you if you don't have enough health.

As always, all items appear in [the game's wiki](http://bindingofisaac.wikia.com/wiki/Items).